# What are these "_embedded.jpg" files that Shotwell created?

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

I have a bunch of these "_embedded.jpg" files alongside my other originals (RAW + JPEG). What are they and why were they created?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: yorba moved to bugzilla, this is the updated link:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718242

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using the "Camera" developer, Shotwell extracts the embedded JPEG from the RAW file and places it beside the file.  This JPEG is then used to display the RAW photo.

There has been some traction on changing this behavior to display the embedded JPEG without extracting it.  See this ticket for more info: [Camera RAW developer wastes disk space by extracting embedded JPEGs](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718242)

Edit: It appears this bug has been resolved; bugs related to shotwell are now here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bugs?field.searchtext=jpeg

Comment: If you could add a note in the settings to tell people about this behaviour, that would be wonderful. :-)